# Visual Studio code, mostrando diretórios de forma estranha

Tags: visual-studio-code

Agora quando estou criando diretórios um dentro do outro utilizando o VS code está alinhando de forma estranha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já desinstalei, instalei novamente mas ainda continua dessa maneira.
Tem como reverter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma configuração chamada "compactFolders", que é ativada por padrão, se você criar as pastas e deixar elas vazias isso vai ocorrer.

Para desativar, você precisa ativar as settings. Isso pode ser feito utilizando as teclas de atalho  + <,> ou clicando no botão Manage (a engrenagem que aparece na parte inferior da tela, no lado esquerdo, na barra onde tem os botões de Arquivos e Extensões.

Ao abrir a tela de Settings, na barra de pesquisa, digite "compactFolders". Na lista que vai aparecer abaixo, basta desativar esta opção